# javascript do shell script

Tags: javascript, macos, shell, applescript

Newbee question -

Now that [OSX/Script Editor.app can do javascript](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/MacAutomationScriptingGuide/GettoKnowScriptEditor.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40016239-CH5-SW1), how do I change my applescript `set a to (do shell script "ls")` to the javascript syntax?

From what I'm reading in the *StandardAdditions.sdef*, `"doShellScript method : Execute a shell script using the ‘sh’ shell"` is the command, so I tried, `doShellScript "ls"` , and the Script Editor (with the Script Language is set to JavaScript) returns,

> "Error -2700: Script error."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to tell your JXA script to use the Standard Additions.

```
app = Application.currentApplication()
app.includeStandardAdditions = true

sourcePath = "/Applications"

// Do not use! Unsafe path-quoting can lead to injection and unwanted behavior! See the update below for the safe version!
app.doShellScript("ls '" + sourcePath + "'").split("\r")
```

***UPDATE:*** 
EDIT After being slapped on the hand by @foo for using a fairly unsafe path-quoting method, the new answer is this:

```
app = Application.currentApplication()
app.includeStandardAdditions = true

sourcePath = "/Applications"

// Safe version!
app.doShellScript("ls '" + sourcePath.replace("'", "'\\''") + "'")
```

Enjoy, Michael / Hamburg

Comment: That did it. Thank you.

Comment: @Shoo: Your example is dangerously unsafe! What happens if sourcePath contains a single quote mark, e.g. "/Users/jsmith/Bob's stuff"? **You must sanitize your inputs** when munging them into a new shell script, e.g. `doShellScript("ls '" + sourcePath.replace("'", "'\\''") + "'")`. If you don't, at best your shell script will fail to run; at worst it will do totally the wrong thing. For example, what if you'd been using `rm -rf` instead? Gods help you if you had another folder named "Bob" on there full of important files, 'cos—Surprise!—now you don't. Always sanitize, sanitize, sanitize!

Comment: @foo: Yes, of course you are right, thank you! My fast written solution just scoped the `doShellScript`, but we as community should take care when answering, especially for Newbies or even for Newbies that will read the answer later! I'll update my answer.

Comment: @CRGreen I quoted you. Your answer _being slapped on the hand_ just hit the point :-D